# Can timeout function be added when getting a string from a URL?

Tags: swift

Sometimes I fetch information from a specific site.
But when the response is slow I would like to add a timeout function. I would like to know how.

Can I add a timeout function to the code below?

```
html = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really supposed to use `init(contentsOf:encoding:)` to read from a remote URL. This initialiser is synchronous so while it is doing that your app's UI will freeze and the user won't be able to do anything, as you may have noticed.

You are supposed to use `URLSession` and `URLRequest` to fetch data from remote URLs. They are asynchronous so you get your data in a completion handler.

You can set a timeout in seconds when you create the `URLRequest`, and you will get an `NSError` in the completion handler if it timed out (among other reasons).

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!,timeoutInterval: 10)
request.addValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "GET"


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {
        print(String(describing: error))
        return
  }
  let result = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
  // do something with result
}

task.resume()
```